# WebSphere MQ certificate interoperability

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

Can the same files used as certificates for SSL authentication in a C♯ program be used within Java, or do the certificate files have to be regenerated specifically for the JDK?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  :-)

The C program needs a KDB and the Java program uses a JKS.  You can convert between these formats.  The result is different files but they represent the same certificate.

The `runmqakm` program does not handle a JKS so you need to use the `runmqckm` program.  Type in the command and it will tell you which parms you left out.  You want the `-convert` option:

```
$runmqckm -keydb
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2014.

An action must be specified for this object.

-Command usage-
Object   Action       Description
------   ------       -----------
-keydb   -changepw    Change the password for a key database
         -convert     Convert the format of a key database
         -create      Create a key database
         -delete      Delete a key database
         -expiry      Display password expiry
         -list        Currently supported types of key database.
         -stashpw     Stash the password of a key database into a file
```

PLEASE be sure to take a copy of the KDB first.  There is at least one bug, depending on the version and Fix Pack you have, in which a syntax error in the command destroys the KDB.

Comment: Thanks very much. Should the runmqckm command be run in the same directory where the dll's used for C# authentication are located? There is no file with a .KDB extension. (There is however a jar file named BC****Exit7.0.jar as opposed to BC****Exit.70R.dll)

Comment: If the MQ Server or client have been installed, the files are in the bin directory.  If there's no kdb and no JKS then you would use whatever tool you've been using to manage the certs to extract the cert and then store it into a JKS using the same tool, keytool or OpenSSL.